# How to overcome openpyxl _x0020_ problem?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to modify an existing xlsx file. Some fields have the string `'_x0020_'`
 in them.

For some reason upon saving the worksheet, the `'_x0020'` is replaced by a space char. I read the values after loading the worksheet and it is still OK.
Any idea?

Comment: What is `'_x0020_'` in your case? an arbitrary sequence of characters that means something in your context? `x0020` happens to be the code for the whitespace character in xml  (an xlsx file is an archive of xml files)

Comment: You're right. I must use it since it's involved with sharepoint

Comment: As I must have this character, any idea how to overcome this behavior?